# IDMF Dynamics AX 2012 stays on Pending for scheduld task

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We want to archive Dynamics AX after a year, and this is after an infrastructure hardware change and a whole IT team changed (including myself).

When i scheduled a task (Meta Sync) in acceptance environment, the task is getting picked up by the AXDataManagementSchedulerService.exe and the Job is getting finished.

If i do the same steps in production environment, the task stays on Pending status (see screenshot), and the logs do not show anything why the task remains stocked. As far as i checked, all the environment variables and services running, are the same as in acceptance environment, and the windows event-viewer doesn't  show any problems.

What could hold the task not to get picked up?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at what questions are considered [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Questions that are not programming related usually have a hard time getting an answer. You might have better luck in other communities, e.g. the [Administration and Setup](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum?pifragment-102905=0&category=Administration%20and%20Setup) area of the Microsoft Dynamics AX Community Forum.